# find -exec on zsh: echo works as expected, print doesn't

Tags: find, zsh

I thought the following two commands would output the same thing, but they don't:

**Command 1:**

> find . -name filename -exec print '{}' \;

**Command 2:**

> find . -name filename -exec echo '{}' \;

In fact, **Command 2** works as I expected it to work: it prints the relative path to all instances of `filename` under `.`

However, for **Command 1** I get as many lines in the output as I get for **Command 2**, but instead of giving me the path, each line says:

```
find: print: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried removing the quotes fron {}.

Why doesn't the second command work as I expected it to work? And why does it fail to print the path to each instance of `filename`?

Comment: `print` isn't actually a standard command anywhere, and if it does exist it most likely is not a synonym for `echo`.  From the error message you get, your system doesn't seem to have `print` in the path at all.  `find` can `-print` file names for you without needing an external command anyways.  Both commands you've listed are poor usage and could be replaced with a simple `find -name filename` since `-print` is the **default action** for `find`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrast:

```
% whence -a print
print
% whence -a echo
echo
/bin/echo
```

This shows that `print` only exists as a built-in, whereas `echo` exists both as a built-in and an executable. (Actually, going by what's shown above, `print` and `echo` could be aliases, functions or reserved words; use `whence -w` to see precisely what type of internal object a name represents.)

`find` is an external command, so it can't invoke any shell built-in. If you really need to invoke your shell's built-ins, invoke a shell explictly:

```
find . -name filename -exec zsh -c 'print "$0"' '{}' \;
```

In this case, I don't think you want zsh's `print` built-in: `find`'s `-print` primary will do the job, only properly (the zsh `print` built-in expands backslashes).

```
find . -name filename -print
```

(You can even leave out the `-print` here, because `-print` is the default action for `find` when no action is specified.)

The reason why there is an `echo` external executable but none called `print` is that `echo` is a standard command, so it's given maximum availability even to programs that want to invoke it without going via a shell. In contrast, `print` is specific to zsh, so only zsh scripts use it in the first place.

(Oh, and on my system, there is a `print` command, which sends files to the printer.)

Answer (score 2):

`find` searches the PATH for a command which matches whatever you specify with '-exec'. `echo` is a actually a binary on your system (for me it's `/bin/each`).

`print`, by contrast is not a binary located on your system, but rather a shell-builtin (look for it [here](http://www.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_17.html)) which find can't exec for you.